# Rearrange RelativeLayout child through java code in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm working on a currency converter app. Everything is working fine. I'm using Nested Linear and Relative Layouts in my xml file. I have arranged the layouts one above the other in RelativeLayout like this. (SIMPLE IDEA)

*--------------RelativeLayout----------*

*------FirstRow------*

*------Divider-------*

*-----secondRow------*

*--------------/RelativeLayout/----------*

I've set the `divider` below `firstRow` and then `secondRow` below `divider` in xml. Now i want to rearrange the rows like this.

*--------------RelativeLayout----------*

*------secondRow------*

*------Divider-------*

*-----firstRow------*

*--------------/RelativeLayout/----------*

I'm trying to do like this `divider` below `secondRow` and `firstRow` below `divider`. but its giving me circular dependencies error. I know all about circular dependencies and i believe the java code is not reseting the above layoutparams, instead its something like merging the two layouts which will definitely shoot circular dependencies error.

> XML CODE

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/namelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_sampleicon" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    style="@style/TextLableMyTheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/brand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#f7f7f7" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tvpoints"
            style="@style/TextCurrencyMyTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_light" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switcherImg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:tint="#f7f7f7" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cash"
                android:tint="#ffe100" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name2"
                    style="@style/TextLableMyTheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Riyal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/brand2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#f7f7f7" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv"
            style="@style/TextCurrencyMyTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="0.0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java Code to update params

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _firstRowParams = 
   (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_firstRow.getLayoutParams();
    _firstRowParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.divider);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _dividerParams = 
   (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_divider.getLayoutParams();
    _dividerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.secondRow);

   /* _firstRow.setLayoutParams(_firstRowParams);
    _divider.setLayoutParams(_dividerParams);*/
```

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams have a method called removeRule() that you need to use in order to **remove** the initial rules set in the xml layout. Keep in mind that this method was added in api level 17, if you support android versions below this you need to create **new** RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instance for the rows and divider.

Comment: i'm on api 15 .. what can i do. can you please help

Comment: As I said, don't reuse the current LayoutParams that you get from getLayoutParams(), instead create new instances of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for each of the rows and the divider with the proper rules and set them on the views.

Comment: great it worked.. thanks. and for api 15 do i need to create everything from scratch(firstRow,SecondRow,Divider and Child views) or just the 3 RelativeLayouts(firstRow,SecondRow,Divider) and use addview to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Luksprog have mentioned about removing the existing rules before adding the new ones this code snippet will work.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _firstRowParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_firstRow.getLayoutParams();
_firstRowParams.removeRule(EXISIING_RULE)//RelativeLayout.Below or RelativeLayout.Above or any other
_firstRowParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.divider);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _dividerParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_divider.getLayoutParams();
_dividerRowParams.removeRule(EXISIING_RULE)//RelativeLayout.Below or RelativeLayout.Above or any other
_dividerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.secondRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _secondRowParams = 
   (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_secondRow.getLayoutParams();
    _secondRowParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
_secondRowParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
```

Try with above code. It worked for me. You need to remove previous **Below** rule to avoid circular dependency.

Comment: still same `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout`